# Replacing JavaApplet with Java Web Start Application

Tags: javascript, java, html, java-web-start

I was using JavaApplet in my Webpage, now I'm working on replacing JavaApplet by Java Web Start Application, I have a problem that in JavaScript I was calling Java methods like this: `int numOfSomething = myAppletID.getNumofSomething();`, but I cannot do this in Java Web Start, how can I solve this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**JavaScript communication is not possible with Java Web Start.**

From [Migrating Java Applets to Java Web Start Applications](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jweb/applet_migration.html#considerations):

> A Java Web Start application does not run within the web browser. So if your applet has any dependency on the browser (for example, Java to JavaScript / JavaScript to Java communications by means of the browser), the communication code will no longer work. The APIs that are affected include: